# SWRLRuleEngineAPI: wrong class format appears in both Eclipse and NetBeans IDEs while doing SWRL inference

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, drools, protege

I have a simple ontology and trying to do SWRL inference. On Protege 3.5 (build 663) the Jess and Drools engines work as expected while using the SWRL API an error occurs. As described in [SWRLRuleEngineAPI](http://protege.cim3.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SWRLRuleEngineAPI) I am using the following code:

```
SWRLRuleEngine ruleEngine = P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory.create(owlModel);
SWRLFactory factory = new SWRLFactory(owlModel);
SWRLImp imp = factory.createImp("Person(?x) ∧ hasGender(?x, male) →  Male(?x)");
ruleEngine.infer();
classes = owlModel.getUserDefinedOWLNamedClasses();
for (Iterator it = classes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    OWLNamedClass cls = (OWLNamedClass) it.next();
    Collection instances = cls.getInstances(false);
    System.out.println("Class " + cls.getBrowserText() + " (" + instances.size() + ")");
    for (Iterator jt = instances.iterator(); jt.hasNext();) {
       OWLIndividual individual = (OWLIndividual) jt.next();
       System.out.println(" - " + individual.getBrowserText());
    }
}
```

All Protege API jars are referenced correctly, the code compiles well and the model is read correctly. But the following error appears on both Eclipse and NetBeans when activating the rule engine `(SWRLRuleEngine ruleEngine = P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory.create(owlModel))`:

> INFO: Updating underlying frames model in 1 ms
>   Rule engine 'Jess' registered with the SWRLTab rule engine manager.
>   Oct 14, 2015 8:00:10 AM org.protege.swrltab.p3.P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory registerRuleEngine
>   INFO: Rule engine 'Jess' registered with the SWRLTab rule engine manager.
>   Plugin 'SWRLJessTab' registered with the SWRLTab plugin manager.
>   Oct 14, 2015 8:00:10 AM edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.swrl.P3SWRLTabPluginManager registerPlugin
>   INFO: Plugin 'SWRLJessTab' registered with the SWRLTab plugin manager.
>   Rule engine 'Drools' registered with the SWRLTab rule engine manager.
>   Oct 14, 2015 8:00:10 AM org.protege.swrltab.p3.P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory registerRuleEngine
>   INFO: Rule engine 'Drools' registered with the SWRLTab rule engine manager.
>   Plugin 'SWRLDroolsTab' registered with the SWRLTab plugin manager.
>   Oct 14, 2015 8:00:10 AM edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.swrl.P3SWRLTabPluginManager registerPlugin
>   INFO: Plugin 'SWRLDroolsTab' registered with the SWRLTab plugin manager.
>   Plugin 'SQWRLQueryTab' registered with the SWRLTab plugin manager.
>   Oct 14, 2015 8:00:10 AM edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.swrl.P3SWRLTabPluginManager registerPlugin
>   INFO: Plugin 'SQWRLQueryTab' registered with the SWRLTab plugin manager.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:251)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:202)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:109)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.superInterfaces(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1152)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.implementsInterface(ReferenceBinding.java:888)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.isCompatibleWith0(ReferenceBinding.java:1036)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.isCompatibleWith(ReferenceBinding.java:987)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.parameterCompatibilityLevel(Scope.java:3963)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.parameterCompatibilityLevel(Scope.java:3951)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.computeCompatibleMethod(Scope.java:555)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getConstructor(Scope.java:1882)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AllocationExpression.resolveType(AllocationExpression.java:359)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:210)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:252)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:422)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1148)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1258)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:763)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:358)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
>       at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:370)
>       at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:47)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:101)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:966)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:802)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:791)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:462)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:664)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:48)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:35)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.defineDRLResource(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.defineDRLRule(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.resetRuleEngine(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngineCreator.create(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrltab.p3.P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory.create(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrltab.p3.P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory.create(Unknown Source)
>       at com.demo.application.OWLAPIDemoApplication.main(OWLAPIDemoApplication.java:107)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.(ClassFileReader.java:372)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:275)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:246)
>       ... 42 more
>   Exception in thread "main" org.protege.swrlapi.exceptions.SWRLRuleEngineException: Error creating rule engine Drools. Exception: org.protege.owl.portability.exceptions.TargetRuleEngineException. Message: internal error generating Drools rule 
>   rule scm_cls when CDA($c:c) then SCA sca1=new SCA($c, $c); ECA eca=new ECA($c, $c); SCA sca2=new SCA($c, "owl:Thing"); SCA sca3=new SCA("owl:Nothing", $c); inferrer.infer(sca1, eca, sca2, sca3); end
>   wrong class format
>       at org.protege.swrltab.p3.P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory.create(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrltab.p3.P3SWRLRuleEngineFactory.create(Unknown Source)
>       at com.demo.application.OWLAPIDemoApplication.main(OWLAPIDemoApplication.java:107)
>   Caused by: org.protege.owl.portability.exceptions.TargetRuleEngineException: internal error generating Drools rule 
>   rule scm_cls when CDA($c:c) then SCA sca1=new SCA($c, $c); ECA eca=new ECA($c, $c); SCA sca2=new SCA($c, "owl:Thing"); SCA sca3=new SCA("owl:Nothing", $c); inferrer.infer(sca1, eca, sca2, sca3); end
>   wrong class format
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.defineDRLRule(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.resetRuleEngine(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngineCreator.create(Unknown Source)
>       ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:251)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:202)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:109)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.superInterfaces(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1152)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.implementsInterface(ReferenceBinding.java:888)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.isCompatibleWith0(ReferenceBinding.java:1036)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.isCompatibleWith(ReferenceBinding.java:987)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.parameterCompatibilityLevel(Scope.java:3963)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.parameterCompatibilityLevel(Scope.java:3951)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.computeCompatibleMethod(Scope.java:555)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getConstructor(Scope.java:1882)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AllocationExpression.resolveType(AllocationExpression.java:359)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolve(LocalDeclaration.java:210)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:252)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:422)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1148)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1258)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:538)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:763)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:358)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
>       at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:370)
>       at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:47)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:101)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:966)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:802)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:791)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:462)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:664)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:48)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:35)
>       at org.protege.swrlapi.drools.DroolsSWRLRuleEngine.defineDRLResource(Unknown Source)
>       ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.(ClassFileReader.java:372)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:275)
>       at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:246)
>       ... 42 more
>   Java Result: 1

UPDATE: After downgrading to Java 7 the following issue appears:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.protege.owl.portability.p3.converters.P3OWLAxiomConverter.completeBulkConversion(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.protege.swrlapi.core.impl.AbstractSWRLRuleEngine.writeInferredKnowledge2OWL(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.protege.swrlapi.core.impl.AbstractSWRLRuleEngine.infer(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.demo.application.OWLAPIDemoApplication.main(OWLAPIDemoApplication.java:125)
>   Java Result: 1

Comment: Check all jars/class files imported to the IDE, and how (compiler version) they were compiled.

Comment: Which Java version are you running this on? From the stack trace I believe this will only run on some specific Java version

Comment: Thanj you @Ignazio. I downgraded from Java 8 to 7 and yet again I received another error (see the update of the question text)

Comment: It's either a problem with the contents of the ontology, or a bug in the SWRLRuleEngineAPI. Can you share the ontology as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Protege version issue. I resolved that by downgrading to the 3.4.8 version which was suggested by Martin O'Connor [Answer](http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/SWRLRuleEngineAPI-wrong-class-format-appears-in-both-Eclipse-and-NetBeans-IDEs-while-doing-SWRL-infee-td4663712.html#a4663767) which has been under extensive review.
Thank you all for your efforts.